# Amazon Route 53: Domain transfer vs Name server update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

We have one domain that is registered in GoDaddy and a web application is running on AWS EC2 instance.

Currently we have pointed the domain to our EC2 application in the following ways:

1. Created Hosted Zone in Amazon Route 53.
2. Updated the name servers (from hosted zone) in GoDaddy name servers update field.
3. A record points to EC2 instance Public IP address.

My question is **do we need to transfer the domain completely into AWS route 53**? Would this help us apply some more features of Route 53 in future?

So which is better: transfer the complete domain to Route 53 or just update the name servers (as we currently chose it)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your GoDaddy configuration is pointing to the Name Servers provided by Route 53, you will have access to the full capabilities of Route 53. There is no need to transfer your domain.

If you do transfer your domain, then it will be managed by Route 53 and will be renewed via your AWS account.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt:)